# OrderBy not having any effect in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-order-by

I have a table that has a set of data in it, as follows:

[image]

Notice the above results are gathered by the following SQL query:

```
select * from Logs where RegisterationId = 16 
 and date = '2018-04-13 00:00:00.000'
order by DateTime ASC;
```

Now this is perfect but when I try to do the same in LINQ using:

```
var logs = db.Logs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
               x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true).OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).Distinct().ToList();
```

it gives all the `Manual_Entry` logs together at the bottom/at the end of the list (notice the index 15,16 & 17 in the snapshots below) and not in the `OrderBy` `DateTime`. I need them sorted exactly the way its done using SQL query:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why `Distinct`? I'm asking because `OrderBy` before `Distinct` / `GroupBy` is ignored by LINQ to Entities sql translator. Remove `Distinct()` or move `OrderBy` after it.

Comment: You also have `x.isIgnore != true` in your Linq that isn't in the original SQL. At the very least you need to be comparing like for like.

Comment: `Distinct` because I want to make sure no repetitive entries are accounted

Comment: `.Distinct()` wont do anything unless you have a comparer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ivan Stoev already mentioned: 
*OrderBy before Distinct / GroupBy is ignored by LINQ to Entities sql translator.*

But if you must use it, use it *before* the `OrderBy`

```
 var logs = db.Logs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= 
                    StartDate && x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

Excluding the `Distinct()` should give you the appropriate list:

```
var logs = db.Logs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= 
                   StartDate && x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true).OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Distinct` destroys order.  Switch the position of the `Distinct` and the `OrderBy` calls.